# How the below program is taking O(n!) time?

Tags: c, algorithm

The complexity of the below program is given to be O(n!)

```
double foo(int n){
    int i;
    double sum;
    if(n==0){
        return 1.0; 
    }
    else {
        sum=0.0;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            sum+=foo(i);
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

But I couldn't determine its complexity as O(n!).
Can anyone explain how is it coming to be O(n!)?

Is it Θ(n!) also or only O(n!)?

If it is not Θ(n!) .Can I get a sample of Θ(n!) code.

Comment: Do you understand how recursion works? Do you know what Θ(n!) and O(n!) mean? Is this homework? If so, how will it help you if we do it for you?

Comment: What is the difference between O(n!) and Θ(n!) ? In school , we use to write both without distinction

Comment: quicksort is O(n!). it is not Θ(n!).

Comment: Just consider what a call foo (10) does.

Comment: @Kabulan0lak, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_o_notation

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia Yes it is

Comment: As per my analysis it is Upper bounded by n! but not exactly n!..so is there any algo which run in exact n!

Comment: @o_weisman Actually on second thought maybe it isn't, since i will always count to 1 less than n, I think eventually it will end.

Comment: @ Kevin DiTraglia there is no infinite recursion.

Comment: @monkey generating permutations is always `n!`

Comment: @ Kabulan0lak there is a difference.

Comment: @ Drew McGowen I think its growth is not as fast as n! It is upper bounded by n!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume the time to calculate foo(n) is T(n). In the case where n>0, we can gather the time taken for an iteration will be:
T(n)=(∑i=0n−1T(i))+n+c
Also, T(1)=c
First, a little justification. The summation in the parenthesis is the run time for all the calls to foo in the loop. The n accounts for the looping and the constant c accounts for things such as initialization, comparisons and such.

Now, with that in mid, let's calculate what the next step would be, and see if we can deduce the growth of the run time.

T(n+1)=(∑i=0nT(i))+(n+1)+c
Now, if from the present sum we extract T(n), we get:

T(n+1)=(∑i=0n−1T(i))+T(n)+(n+1)+c
Now, if we rearrange the result in the following way, we have an opportunity for reducing the sum:

T(n+1)=[(∑i=0n−1T(i))+n+c]+T(n)+1
You see that in the brackets, that's exactly what we defined as T(n) (1rst equation). In that case, we get that:

T(n+1)=T(n)+T(n)+1=2T(n)+1
From this, it also stands that T(n)=2T(n−1)+1. What happens if we replace T(n−1) by it's value calculated with this very function? Well, let's iterate:

T(n)=2T(n−1)+1=2[2T(n−2)+1]+1=2[2[2T(n−3)+1]+1]+1⋮=2kT(n−k)+k
Almost there. Finally, let's write it in terms of T(0), our known base case. First, for that we must have T(n−k)=T(0) so it stands that k=n. In the end, we get:

T(n)=2nT(0)+n=2nc+n
With this in mind, we can conclude that T(n)=θ(2n)

Answer (score 1):

Your code computes the powers of two. *Prove it* (hint: induction). This should give you a clue about its *theta* complexity. Prove that by induction as well.

Another hint. After you compute it, you'll notice the big-theta complexity of your program is less than n!. Assuming your exact complexity is f(n), a simple way to prove it's "less" than n! is to compute the limit of f over n! as n goes to infinity.

That means that your big-O complexity is in the O(n!) class. Prove that by the definition of big-O class.

As for an example of theta (n!) code, you can figure a way to write a factorial function in a *very* inefficient way.

Comment: It is. It is also in O(n^n), and O(n^n^n) and (exp(n!)) as well, you get the picture. The point is to provide an exact complexity class which is *less* than O(yourfunction), as your big-O complexity will therefore be in O(yourfunction) as well; check out big-O definition.

Comment: @webuster How do you prove big-theta *first* and go on from there to *then* prove big-o? Shouldn't that be the other way around?

Comment: Well the solution I was suggesting involved computing the *exact* complexity first. Big-theta and big-O will both immediately follow. If you can't compute the exact complexity, you can always take some bounds. In that case you can compute a big-O complexity class by just taking an upper bound and prove an inequality.

Comment: Please check the solution I have got... http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/29108/how-the-below-program-is-taking-on-time/29110#29110

Comment: Please check this solution is it right? http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/29108/how-the-below-program-is-taking-on-time/29110#29110

Comment: Yes. Rigorous. I suggested induction because it may be easier to write once you observe a pattern. For example you might have tried computing `foo(i)` for the first ten values of `i`, counting the number of steps each computation took and then tried to make a more robust proof by induction. Processing a recursive formula is just as good.

Comment: complexity of above function is actually theta(2^n)

Comment: ... which is also in O(n!) :) I did not imply otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

O(n!) gives you the upper bound , where as , Θ(n!) gives you the exact bound of the function.

```
double foo(int n){  
int i;
double sum;
if(n==0){            // time=1;
    return 1.0;     // time++;           
}
else {             // if the condition is is not satisfied then else executes ,time=1;
    sum=0.0;                    //time++;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){           
        sum+=foo(i);            //n times foo()  ; therefore , 2+n(foo());
    }
    return sum;                 //time++;
}
```

now if you solve this recurrence  using the recursion tree method it will O(n!)